# Changing JSF ManagedBeans to Spring Component

Tags: spring, jsf, aop

I'm working with JSF and Spring after a while i found that i need to use Spring's AOP in my managed beans but as I changed them from for instance:

```
@ManagedBean("title")
@RequestScope
public class Title{
   ...
}
```

(which works seamless) to

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class Title{
   ...
}
```

although spring tries to create those bean as I need (as it sets some Autowired properties ) but it can not find some of its properties referenced from my .xhtml files and says for example :

```
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwarePropertyNotFoundException:   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'selectedUser' not found on type $Proxy50
```

any body can help?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to apply Spring AOP to class that implements any interfaces, you should either include all public methods of that class into interfaces implemented by it, or configure AOP with `proxy-target-class = "true"`.

See [7.6 Proxying mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying) for explanation of this behavior.

Comment: tanx it was another problem of mine but now my major problem is that when I change it to spring beans it can not find some of those properties !!

Comment: i think spring creates the bean but use another one. how can i check whether the proxy object is attached to the correct object???

Answer (score 0):

If your xhtml jsf page can't access your Spring Beans, check that you have the following config in your faces-config.xml :

```
<application>
     <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```